# How to store a complex json response from api in local database in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, local-storage

I want to save the whole json response from api. I tried SQFLITE library to store but i cant able to achieve to store a complete json as it need to store in a  table format. I'm very new to flutter. can any body suggest how can i achieve this. Below i'm attaching my sample json for your reference.

```
{
  "result": {
    "allitems": {
      "answered_status": 0,
      "list_items": [
        {
          "is_answered": false,
          "options": [
            {
              "image_url": "assets/images/orders/jersey.jpg",
              "description": "Jersey",
              "title": "Jersey",
              "price": 23
            },
            {
              "image_url": "assets/images/orders/bat.png",
              "description": "Bat",
              "title": "Bat",
              "price": 5
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      "no_of_items": 12,
      "title": "ALL"
    }

  },
  "status_code": 200
}
```

Comment: By local database do you mean locally on a device? If that's the case then you can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package to do that, but first you have to take the response into a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` then encode it into JSON by using [`jsonEncode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) method.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for your response. If i use shared prefences, can i able to update any of the attributes in the above json when i get response from the user? I have to do CRUD operation on my data which is stored in local.

Comment: Yes, of course, I will compose an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wrong about `SharedPreferences` in my comment. Turns out `SharedPreferences` doesn't support `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` and only up to `List<String>` yet.

So you can use a database management package [`sembast`](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast) made by the same guy who made `SQFLite`.

You can get help with [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) link to convert JSON objects to `Map` and vice-versa.

EDIT -

---

You can do something like -

```dart
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';

Map<dynamic, dynamic> sampleMap;

// Skipping this part
sampleMap = // Retrive and convert JSON to Map

// A sample DB in the current directory
String dbPath = 'sample.db';
DatabaseFactory dbFactory = databaseFactoryIo;

// We use the database factory to open the database
Database db = await dbFactory.openDatabase(dbPath);

var store = intMapStoreFactory.store();

// Storing Map to DB
var key = await store.add(db, sampleMap);

// Retrieving values back
var record = await store.record(key).getSnapshot(db);

// From your provided sample JSON in question
var value = record["result"]["allitems"]["list_items"][0]["options"]["image_url"];

print(value);
// value = 'assets/images/orders/jersey.jpg'
```

Similarly, you can explore the documentation of the package for more data operations.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments. tiil record i'm getting the response but i cant able to get the response in value(i.e, var value = record['result.allitems.list_items.options[0].image_url']; it returns null). can you help me in that?

Comment: You were able to store your response in Map and then store that to a local database ?

Comment: Yes i can able to store response in Map and then store that to a local database

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek i got output by changing var value = record["result"]["allitems"]["list_items"][0]["options"][index]["title"];

Comment: Edited. Good to see it works, it will help me also in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a string, you can store it in shared preference.

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
var s = json.encode(myMap);
// or var s = jsonEncode(myMap);

json.decode()/jsonDecode() makes a map from a string when you load it.
```